# Configuring WSO2 API Manager to Work With Traefik for HTTPS

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager, traefik

I am trying to configure Traefik and WSO2 API Manager. Basically, I want to configure Traefik to handle https.

```
     labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.service-am-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.service-am-http.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.routers.service-am-http.rule=Host(`xx.xx.xx`) && Path(`/apim/admin`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.service-am-http.middlewares=service-am-https@docker"
        - "traefik.http.routers.service-am.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.service-am.rule=Host(`xx.xx.xx`) && Path(`/apim/admin`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.service-am.entrypoints=web-secure"
        - "traefik.http.services.service-am.loadbalancer.server.port=9443"
```

I also included this in the `deployment.toml` file for API Manager.

```
[catalina.valves.valve.properties]
className = "org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
internalProxies = "*"
remoteIpHeader ="x-forwarded-for"
proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
trustedProxies="*"
```

When I try to access the service, `https://xx.xx.xx/apim/admin`, I get this error:

```
Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.
```

Traefik is successfully handling the https part but when it comes to WSO2 API Manager, this issue comes up. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Just to understand the requirement is this the expected scenario? 
`client ==https==> traefik ==http==>apim ==> backend`
if this is the case you shouldn't forward http traffic from traefik to https port of apim. use 9763 (http) port. 9443 is listening only for https traffic not http.

Comment: I tried that also. But APIM redirects the browser to 9443.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and solved including

```
 annotations:
   ingress.kubernetes.io/protocol: https
```

in my Ingress.

The full configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: wso2-ingress
 namespace: <namespace>
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
   traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
   ingress.kubernetes.io/protocol: https
spec:
 rules:
 - host: <hostname>
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /
       backend:
         serviceName: <service-name>
         servicePort: 9443
```

Comment: +poithar. Thanks but I'm not using the Kubernetes Ingress Provider in Traefik.